# How to find the smallest integer in subgroup of Z

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

What is the smallest positive integer (i) in $7\mathbb{Z}\cap9\mathbb{Z}$?
(ii) $7\mathbb{Z}+9\mathbb{Z}$? where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers.

I said that $7\mathbb{Z}\cap9\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$ but then I can't conclude, the smallest integers do not really exists no? 
For $7\mathbb{Z}+9\mathbb{Z}$, said that it was equal to $63\mathbb{Z}$, but again there, there is an infinite number of numbers in $63\mathbb{Z}$, how can I find the smallest? It seems like I don't really get the question...

Comment: $7\Bbb Z\cap 9\Bbb Z = \{x\in \Bbb Z~:~7\mid x~\text{and}~9\mid x\}$.  Numbers that are simultaneously divisible by $7$ and divisible by $9$ can be characterized as being divisible by some number.  What number?  Think about greatest common divisors.  Meanwhile $7\Bbb Z+9\Bbb Z = \{x+y~:~7\mid x~\text{and}~9\mid y\}$

Comment: Another comment., "*there is an infinite number of numbers in $63\Bbb Z$, how can I find the smallest?*"  You are correct, there are, and no you can not find the smallest, it is unbounded.  *However!* You *can* find the smallest *positive* such number by the well ordered principle.  Note that $63\Bbb Z = \{\dots,-126,-63,0,63,126,\dots\}$.  It should be clear what the smallest *positive* number in it is.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're a little confused on the definitions here.

What does it mean for $x$ to be in $7 \mathbb{Z} \cap 9 \mathbb{Z}$? It means that $x$ is both a multiple of 7 and a multiple of 9. What's the smallest positive multiple of both 7 and 9 you can think of?

As for $7 \mathbb{Z} + 9 \mathbb{Z}$: any element in here is of the form $7a + 9b$, for integers $a$ and $b$. There is a way to find the smallest positive integer that can be expressed as a linear combination of two integers, have you encountered this before?

Comment: Thank you so much. You made it so much more clear. I think it is the gcd/hcf of 7 and 9 that I can find using Euclid method?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right

Answer (score 1):

No. The smallest positive integer in $a\mathbf Z\cap b\mathbf Z$ is just the l.c.m. of $a$ and $b$, and when $a$ and $b$ are coprime, it is nothing else but their product.

As to  $a\mathbf Z+ b\mathbf Z$, it is generated by $\gcd(a,b)$.